# How do I update my American Megatrends BIOS?

Tags: bios

I have an ASUSTek P7H55-M LX.  System Info says BIOS is American Megatrends Inc. 0402, 10/29/2010.  When I visit http://www.ami.com/support/ "BIOS updates" goes to a site that wants $30.  Do they not offer free updates?

Comment: What happens when you visit the ASUS website instead? I was able to find quite a lot on http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=P7H55-M+LX&p=1&s=32.

Comment: Well aren't you a crazy genius.   If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This question got -1 votes in total, but over 1000 views. Maybe someone should vote it up a little. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're looking in the wrong place.

The ASUS Support website is better. I found a wealth of downloads at http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=P7H55-M+LX&p=1&s=32.